# Is it bad for performance to retrieve a state value directly using computed(() => myStore().myList)?

Tags: javascript, pinia

I have taken the habit to declare Pinia stores as such:

```
// store.js
export const myStore = defineStore("myStore", {
  state: () => ({
    myList: null
  })
});

//Component.vue
<script setup>
  import { myStore } from "./myStore";
  const myList = computed(() => myStore().myList)
</script>
```

The main reason for that is that I find my code less obvious/more convoluted if I instead write:

```
<script setup>
  import { myStore } from "./myStore";
  const myStoreContents = myStore().myList
  const myList = computed(() => myStoreContents.myList)
</script>
```

or something like that.

However, I now wonder if my way of usually doing it, calling the store's exported function in `computed` is bad for performance or is considered a bad practice for one reason or another?

Comment: This would leave around an extra variable MyStoreContents that likely wouldn't get cleaned up by the JavaScript trash collector unless MyList also gets trashed so there is that extra memory being taken there. Though I assume this myStore().myList doesn't create a new duplicate of the imported store so the variable myStoreContents will likely just be a reference to that list, so it would be negligible. I know nothing of Pinia so take that into account.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. @ColinHale Yeah, what I wonder is precisely whether calling myStore() multiple times has an impact on performance or if it is, like you suggest, only a reference to the previously accessed store